# Why Rails rollback transaction sliently when thread is aborting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As you can see in the [source code of transaction](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb#L326), it will rollback the transaction if thread is aborting:

```
if Thread.current.status == "aborting"
   rollback_transaction
...
```

So I want to create some logs on thread exit won't work:

```
Thread.new do
  begin
    # infinite loop, or do a long time task
  ensure
    post.update!(foo: 'bar')
    # do something
  end
end
```

Also `post.update!(foo: 'bar')` rollbacked silently without raise an exception. Although I replaced `update!` with `update_column` instead, as `update_column` is not wrapped with a transaction. but I still want to know why Rails rollbacked the transaction, and even silently? Without warning log?

Comment: Based on the original PR that added that linked code (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13656), it looks like it's there to handle the case where a thread is killed externally with Thread#kill (the intent being to avoid partially-complete operations, since such a kill does not raise an actual exception to trigger normal rollback procedures). That doesn't seem to be the case in your example. Are you positive your thread is actually running? Try calling `.join` on the thread instance to be sure it's executing before your process executes.

Comment: @RobertNubel Thanks for the link, in fact, it's the same case for me,  my thread is looping inside the `begin` block, so the `ensure` block will run when I hit `ctrl + c`

Comment: Update question with  evidence for what you are claiming rails is doing. Right now this seems like speculation.

Comment: You should be able to check thread state from ensure block also.

Comment: why don't try commit current transaction before thread is aborted: `Post.connection.commit_db_transaction`?